# How to display friendly messages during MFA login

Tags: javascript, .net, azure, multi-factor-authentication

I have a website witch uses forms-authentication. Now I have added Microsoft Azure MFA on-prem to the server and it works great..

But the user experience is not so good.

When the user logs in, the page just keeps "loading", until he approves on his app.

I would like to display a massage to the user, that he must approve using the app..
Just like when you are loggin on to the office 365 portal.

Does anyone have a solution?

I have tried using javascript, but the page freezes when pushing the login button.